# Recall an email using Microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using [microsoft graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mail-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) to fetch emails from office365. There is need to have recall functionality  but not able to locate the required api.
Can someone help me in here. I am not sure if such API even exists

Answer (score 0):

There is no endpoint in the Graph for message recall it's all private API's in the clients that implemented it. You could add this as a feature request for the the graph https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform